# Can't clear the stdin using fflush(stdin), after using getchar(), in an infinite for loop C prog

Tags: c, for-loop, infinite-loop, getchar, fflush

I have just started off with C programming and while I was trying to write a programme to accept only y or n characters I came across that

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char ch;
  printf("Do you want to continue\n");

  for (;;)
    {
      ch=getchar();
      if (ch=='Y' || ch=='y')
        {
            printf("Sure!\n");
            break;
        }
        else if (ch=='N'||ch=='n')
        {
            printf("Alright! All the best!\n");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("You need to say either Yes/No\n");
            fflush(stdin);
        }

    }
    return(0);
}
```

When I run this code, and type in any other character other than Y/y or N/n, I receive the last printf statement (You need to say either Yes/No) as output twice. 
I understand that this is happening because it considers enter, i.e, '\n' as another character. 
Using fflush doesn't help as it's an infinite loop. 
How else can I modify it so that the last statement is displayed only once?

Comment: `char ch` should be `int ch` please read more about [getchar](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getchar.htm) function

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour. No further research required.

Comment: @Olaf: For better or worse, using `fflush(stdin)` is defined behaviour if the platform is Microsoft; it is undefined on other platforms.  The gory details are at [Using `fflush(stdin)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin).  Until we know which platform, your statement is too sweeping.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I stricktly follow the tags given. The C tag implies C standard, which is very [clear about that](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.2p2). Hmm, I wonder if an implementation does define a behaviour the standard states is undefined: does that make the implementation non-compliant? :-)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm not sure the link sheds that much light on the subject anyway. The notes (yours) say both linux and windows define `fflush` for input streams (and in the same way) -- however, `fflush (stdin)` does *not* empty the input buffer, so I'm lost on the distinction you are drawing here -- help?

Comment: @Michi: Why should it matter whether I declare it as char or int? The problem still remains. I did try with int, I still have the same issue.

Comment: @ArshithaBasavaraj: Because a `char` very likely cannot hold all possible return values of a function which returns an `int`! This is very critical for `getchar`, as you should check for `EOF`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler's comment is relevant. Since MSVC does implement `fflush(stdin)` the code behaves well. Since OP's system does not, the prompt is printed twice: once for the undesired char, once for the `newline` which follows.

Comment: @ArshithaBasavaraj Please check my Answer

Comment: @olaf I understand that. I did try declaring it as int, no luck. When I asked how it mattered, I meant wrt the problem I'm facing, which is, that the enter escape sequence is not being cleared by fflush(stdin)

Comment: @ArshithaBasavaraj: It is a problem on its own. Just be happy to get some extra hints.

Comment: @olaf I guess it is, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop to read any characters left using `getchar()`:

```
  ch=getchar();
  int t;
  while ( (t=getchar())!='\n' && t!=EOF );
```

The type of `ch` should `int` as `getchar()` returns an `int`. You should also check if `ch` is `EOF`.

`fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour per C standard. Though, it's *defined* for certain platforms/compilers such as Linux and MSVC, you should avoid it in any portable code.

Comment: I have small doubt, why is it that we use && in the while loop statement? Why doesn't an || condition work?

Comment: Because we want to break the infinite loop if *either* of that condition is false. If, for example, the function returns `EOF` to signal "no more input", then using `||` will lead to infinite loop as  `(t=getchar())!='\n'` will be true. In `if (A || B)`, the condition `B` will not be evaluated if `A` is true. See [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). So `&&` is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Another option - use `scanf` ignoring white spaces.

Instead of `ch=getchar();`, just need `scanf( " %c", &ch );`

With this you can also get rid of `fflush(stdin);`

Answer (score 0):

Like is said in my comment you should use `int ch` instead of `char ch` because the return type of `getchar` which is `int`.

To clean `stdin` you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
  int ch,cleanSTDIN;
  printf("Do you want to continue\n");

  for (;;)
    {
      ch = getchar();
      while((cleanSTDIN = getchar()) != EOF && cleanSTDIN != '\n');
      if (ch=='Y' || ch=='y')
        {
            printf("Sure!\n");
            break;
        }
        else if (ch=='N'||ch=='n')
        {
            printf("Alright! All the best!\n");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("You need to say either Yes/No\n");
        }

    }
    return(0);
}
```

Any way a do while will probably do the job for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char ch;
    int check;

    do {
        printf("Do you want to continue: ");

        if ((scanf("%c",&ch)) == 1){
            while((check=getchar()) != EOF && check != '\n');

            if ((ch == 'y') || (ch == 'Y')){
                printf("Alright! All the best!\n");
                break;
            } else if((ch == 'n') || (ch == 'N')){
                printf("You choosed %c\n",ch);
                break;
            }else{
                printf("You need to say either Yes/No\n");
            }
        }else{
            printf("Error");
            exit(1);
        }

    }while (1);

    return 0;
}
```

Output1:

```
Do you want to continue: g
You need to say either Yes/No
Do you want to continue: y
Alright! All the best!
```

Output2:

```
Do you want to continue: n
You choosed n
```

Answer (score 0):

Or we can simply use another `break;` statement after the last `printf()`.